# AWS SQS temporary queues not being deleted on app shutdown

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We are attempting to use the [aws sqs temporary queues library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client) for synchronous communication between two of our apps. One app utilises a `AmazonSQSRequester` while the other uses a `AmazonSQSResponder` - both are created using the builders from the library and wired in as Spring beans in app config. Through AWS console we create an SQS queue to work as the 'host queue' required for the request/return pattern. The requesting app sends to this queue and the responding app uses a [SQSMessageConsumer](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/util/SQSMessageConsumer.java) to poll the queue and pass messages to the `AmazonSQSResponder`. Part of how (I'm fairly sure) the library works is that the Requester spins up a temporary SQS queue (a real, static one), then sends that queue url as an attribute in a message to the Responder, which then posts its response there.

Communications between the apps work fine and temporary queues are automatically created. The issue is that when the Requester app shuts down, the temporary queue (now orphaned and useless) persists when it should be cleared up by the library. Information on how we're expecting this clean up to work can be found in [this aws post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/simple-two-way-messaging-using-the-amazon-sqs-temporary-queue-client/):

> The Temporary Queue Client client addresses this issue as well. For each host queue with recent API calls, the client periodically uses the TagQueue API action to attach a fresh tag value that indicates the queue is still being used. The tagging process serves as a heartbeat to keep the queue alive. According to a configurable time period (by default, 5 minutes), a background thread uses the ListQueues API action to obtain the URLs of all queues with the configured prefix. Then, it deletes each queue that has not been tagged recently.

The problem we are having is that when we kill the Requester app, unexplained messages appear in the temporary queue/response queue. We are unsure which app puts them there. Messages in queue prevent the automagic cleanup from happening. The unexplained messages share the same content, a short string:

> .rO0ABXA=

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it was logged as a bug with the library: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client/issues/11. Will hopefully be fixed soon!